# How to get first td text from a tr by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get a text of cell in a tr row.
The tr row has class attr and a data- attr.
I select the tr row as

```
var k = $('tr[class="BatchTypesRow"][data-rowselected="true"]');
```

then

```
var m = k.children("td:first");    
var sBtype = m.text();    
alert(sBtype);
```

the sBtype contains all cells' text in the row.
I tried

```
var sBtype = m[0].text();
```

that catches an exception.

So what is the problem here?
If the cell is not the first cell in the row, how to do it?

Comment: share your html sample as well

Comment: and what's the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `m` itself is the first `td` of the row since `var m = k.children("td:first");`

So `m.text()` would not give the whole row as long as `td:first` is selected. If you use `.children("td")` then you would be getting the whole row in `m.text()`. So in your code,

```
var sBtype = m.text();    
alert(sBtype);
```

would actually give the First cell content.

If not the first cell, you would be using `var m = k.children("td");` removing the keyword `first`. In this case m[0] would have the first cell, m[1] second and so on.

Correct me if am wrong, I believe this is how you got the exception, using `m[0].text()` would throw you an exception since m[0],m[1] are not JQuery object. They are HTMLTableCellElement Object.

To use it as a JQuery object, you would have to use `$(m[1]).text()`.

And if you know which element to be selected w.r.t its sequence, you can use

```
var m = k.children("td:nth-child(n)");
```

where you can replace `n` with the number so that you will select the `nth td` of the row.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr.selected td:first-child').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, select the tr within which lies the text.for which you can use the class attr

$("tr.BatchTypesRow")

then traverse down the tree to get the td ie its children

$("tr.BatchTypesRow").children("td")

as you need the first child ,is the first td as you traverse through the selected tr ,it can be further written as

$("tr.BatchTypesRow").children("td:first")

if the text lies within a label inside the selected td

```
$("tr.BatchTypesRow").children("td:first").children("label").text();
```

will give you the desired text .